# GetPixel in GDI

Tags: c++, c, windows, gdi

Using GetPixel, Is that right that you retrieve the pixel information that HDC temporarily store after you draw on each WM_PAINT call?

Answer (score 0):

It will get the x,y pixel value of whatever bitmap is selected within the HDC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28VS.85%29.aspx

GetPixel is quite slow, if I recall correctly. Depending on what you want to do, it will probably be a lot faster to access the raw bitmap data directly.

Comment: But when you do that, I'm not certain whether GDI will flush all operations directly to your raw bitmap (i.e. _during_ the WM_PAINT, between `BeginPaint()` and `EndPaint()` your bitmap may be out of sync.) Raymond Chen recently wrote on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/23/10066473.aspx. You could of course "fix" that by calling `GdiFlush`, like `GetPixel` does. But that probably just makes direct access equally slow as calling GetPixel in the first place.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm not certain but suspect it's more than GdiFlush making GetPixel/SetPixel slow. (Unless GdiFlush is very poorly implemented. :)). If there's nothing to flush, GdiFlush should be instant. Calling GetPixel in a loop, only the first flush (at most) should slow things down. I think there's more overhead to GetPixel than just the flush. e.g. Potentially having to talk to the GPU (if the bitmap is in GPU memory), work out what kind of bitmap and pixel/color layout/format its dealing with on every call, etc. IMO, getting the raw data once and looping should be faster (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

It depends, not all devices support GetPixel. An application should call GetDeviceCaps to determine whether a specified device supports this function.